# Slack + Heroku: Send notification to slack whenever my Heroku app is down

Tags: heroku, slack, slack-api

I have a Heroku app and whenever I deploy on Heroku a notification is received on my production channel at Slack.

I wanted to follow the same procedure for my Heroku app going down for any reason.
Any recommended way !

Comment: Although your question is a bit outside the usual scope of stackoverflow, here is a recommendation anyway. Check out the web service https://uptimerobot.com/. Its a web service for monitoring websites and web services. it has a build in connector for Slack and is free for up to 50 monitors. That is what I use to monitor all my Slack apps.