# How do I Redirect Heroku Error logs to Slack

Tags: heroku

What I want to achieve is:

1. Filter Error logs from Heroku logs
2. Send only the Error logs to a Slack Channel

I have checked [deployhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604177/slack-heroku-send-notification-to-slack-whenever-my-heroku-app-is-down) but these only work for Deployments and also [Heroku ChatOps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/chatops) is also only for Deployments.

Is there a way to constantly tail the logs and redirect the error log to Slack?

One way I can achieve this is using:

```
heroku logs -t --app app-name | grep "error" > redirect to slack based on webhook
```

But this requires configuring Heroku cli on a machine and also allowing messages to be posted to slack from that machine.
Can this be directly configured to Heroku itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Sorry to say that there's nothing baked into the platform to support streaming exceptions/errors to Slack. That said, you should be able to accomplish this a number of ways. Some more work than others.

For instance, on the low-effort ends you can set up Rollbar for the application in question and it looks like Rollbar [natively supports a Slack integration](https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/slack). It's more work but you could also build a custom application to more or less pipe things directly to Slack while listening to the log stream.

Answer (score 0):

As @RangerRanger mentioned there is no way to do this on Heroku without using addons.

I found two add-ons which are easy to configure and allow filtration of logs in real-time and sends messages to slack.

You can use [PaperTrail](https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/integrations/slack/#setup) which is easier to configure or use [Coralogix](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/coralogix) which gives you Kibana support.